# Getting an Internal server Error when trying to post product with angular Js (MEAN Stack)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I really need some help. I'm facing with an Internal Server error when i try to add product through http service ($http.post) in angular js. So basically, the files you need to help me to get out from this frustration are:

**index.js : Here I define api routes of my express server

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router(); 
var productCtrl = require('../controllers/productCtrl'); 

router.get('/products', productCtrl.getAllProducts); 
router.get('/products/:productId', productCtrl.readProduct); 
router.post('/products', productCtrl.createProduct); 
router.delete('/products/:productId', productCtrl.removeProduct); 
router.put('/products/:productId', productCtrl.updateProduct); 

module.exports = router;
```

**product.js : The product model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}, 
  category: {type: String, default: ''}, 
  price: { type: Number, default: 0}, 
  picture: String, 
  pictures: [String], 
  quantity: {type: Number, default: 0}, 
  status: { 
    type: String, 
    enum: ['Pending', 'In Progress', 'Cancelled', 'Done'], 
    default: 'Pending' 
 }, 
   date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}, 
   description: { type: String}, 
   owner: {type: String}
 }); 

 var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema); 

 module.exports = Product;
```

**productCtrl.js: My controller on Express Server where i build a rest API

```
var Product = require('../models/product'); 

var sendJsonResponse = function (res, status, content ){
   res.status(status); 
   res.json(content); 
}

 /* some other code here, but i will only show create action */ 
 module.exports.createProduct = function (req, res){
  Product
      .create({
        name: req.body.name, 
        category: req.body.category, 
        price: req.body.price, 
        picture: req.body.picture, 
        pictures: req.body.pictures.split(", "), 
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        status: req.body.status, 
        date: req.body.date, 
        description: req.body.description, 
        owner: req.body.owner

      }, function createProduct(err, product){
        if(err){
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err); 
            return; 
        }
        else {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 201, product); 
        }
      });
 }
```

And finally in my angular module script file : app.js

```
(function(){ 
   var app = angular.module('ecommerce', []); 

   app.controller('ProductController', 
   ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http){
    console.log('Welcome to the ProductController'); 
     /* some other code here */

    $scope.addProduct = function (){ 

        var newProduct = {
                    name: $scope.product.name, 
                    category: $scope.product.category, 
                    price: $scope.product.price, 
                    picture: $scope.product.picture, 
                    pictures: [], 
                    quantity: 10,  
                    status: "Pending", 
                    date: Date.now(), 
                    description: $scope.product.description, 
                    owner: "Joel Alexandre Khang Zulbal"
        }; 

        console.log(newProduct); 
        alert("Passing variable..."); 

        $http.post('/api/products', newProduct)
             .then( function onSuccessCallback(){
                    $scope.products.push($scope.product); 
                        alert("Success Insertion"); 
                        $scope.$apply(); 
                 }, function onErrorCallback (error){
                        console.log(error); 
                        alert("Insertion failed!!"); 
                 }); 

            $scope.product = {}; 
            $scope.close(); 
    }
    /* some other code here */

}]); 

})()
```

And also my entry server point: app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./app_api/routes/index'); 
var users = require('./routes/users');
require('./app_api/models/database.js'); 

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api); 
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

 // error handlers

 // development error handler
 // will print stacktrace
 if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
  message: err.message,
  error: err
  });
 });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: {}
  });
});


 module.exports = app;
```

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong here! So please guys help me

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Do you have some express code that you didn't show that is mapping the request from `/api/products` to `/products`? If not, have you tried just `$http.post('/products', newProduct)`?

Comment: First of all, in my command propmt where i run my express server code: I'm  getting this error :   `POST /api/products 44.297 ms - 4369 `    In my google chrome web browser, i have this error message  `Failed to load resource: the server response with a status of 500`

Comment: What about my other suggestions? Do you have another file with express logic?

Comment: No just those files.  (sorry for my low english level)

Answer (score 0):

`express.Router` is used when you want to have multiple separate apps, for example one router that handles `/users/get/1` and `/users/list` and another second one that handles `/products/get/1` and `/products/list`.

In your case, you can skip using `express.Router`. Based on what you've shown, it is overcomplicating things. Try this:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var productCtrl = require('../controllers/productCtrl'); 

// ... other routes here
// note that you can change the next line to /api/products, or change your angular code to POST to /products (without the /api part):
app.post('/api/products', productCtrl.createProduct); 
// ... other routes here

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this. I will give you a feedback

Comment: You know it's not an error from my Express server side because when i'm using postman and i make post request the data has been added in my database. The problem is my client side with Angular JS i think, i don't know if i'm not sending a request with a good headers or something else... I'm really confuse

Comment: Ok, well *now* you've added more express code, which is exactly what I was asking about yesterday. Let me take a look